# Are users likely to change default text?

Tags: language

I have a site where somebody can set up and collect information using a [Triangle test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrimination_testing#Triangle). The issue I'm facing is that there is standard and correct copy to use when presenting somebody with this type of question.

I currently provide default text as not to skew results. If it was changed to something like: "Group the two that are the same together", that would be wrong from a statistical standpoint that I'm not going to get into here.
I still want to have them able to change the text.

Is there any studies that you know of that says that users **are** or **are not** likely to change default text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you will find any standard answer about whether users change default text.  That is far too context-dependent.  The question is: are users likely to change the text on your particular application?  It depends on your particular users and use case.

As for the issue itself, you have two conflicting goals:

- Ensure that the test conforms to standards of validity.
- Give users the flexibility to customize the test.

There is no way to have both.  If you allow the users to edit the text, that *necessarily* means that they can create an invalid test if they want to do so.

The best way to frame this issue is probably in terms of costs/benefits to users.  How useful will it be for them to customize the text?  How likely are they to inadvertantly get it wrong and produce invalid results?  We aren't able to assess this with the information you have given.

If you do allow users to change the text, you can help guide them by providing easily accessible information explaining what constitutes a valid question, the dangers of getting it wrong, etc.